# Listing an image gallery based on ranking

Tags: mongodb, pagination, document

I'm creating a website with a feed of images ( similar to pinterest). I want to list those images in the ascending order of their popularity ( no of likes and views each images receives) with pagination.

Im confused on how to implement this ..

We are using mongoDB, 
Document has the following fields
1. _id
2. user_id
3. image_id
4. score  ( which is value of popularity,( no of views) + 10x (no of likes))
5. Rank

We are thinking of running a script daily to calculate the value of score. 
And run a loop script to assign the rank ( image with highest score get 1st rank, second highest gets rank 2 etc).

The feed then fetches the images in the ascending order of the rank. 
Running such a script of millions of such documents will take a lot of time.
Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

you can try different approaches for your needs, implement them and find the best.

1. your idea: background job (at night) to calculate field in db
2. on update page: select images, order by likes*10 + views desc
3. on every image view or like, update image rank

Comment: Don't you think updating image rank on every like would be expensive operation.